# When we say that test has 25% false negatives, do we mean P(~e|H)=0.25 or P(H|~e)=0.25?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, bayes-theorem

P(H) means probability of hypothesis H, namely probability of picking a sick person out of the pool of people who took the test. P(~e) means probability of negative result of a test for sickness. In other words, it's probability that the test will say that randomly picked person is healthy.

Here P(~e|H) would mean probability of picking a person with negative test result from the pool of sick people. As for P(H|~e), it would mean probability of picking a sick person out of pool of people with negative test result.

It makes me wonder, what exactly do we mean when we talk about false negatives? Do we mean P(~e|H) or P(H|~e)? And why?

Comment: A [false negative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_positives_and_false_negatives) occurs when a sick person tests as healthy.

Comment: @lulu I know that. I wonder how probability is calculated.

Comment: So, the probability of a false negative refers to the probability that, given a sick person, you nonetheless get a negative result.

Comment: @lulu I see, now it makes sense. But why can't we use P(H|~e) as alternative way of measuring efficiency of the test?

Comment: @lulu By the way, can't we also say that false negative occurs when a person with negative result turns out to be sick?

Comment: You certainly can keep track of that other measure, why not?  But the standard is to do it this way.

Comment: As a practical matter, the measure you propose conflates the number of sick people with the desired probability.  For instance, if $.01\%$ of the population has the disease but half of those test negative, then it is still the case that the percentage of sick people amongst the negative scores is very low.  This would disguise the fact that the test is, in fact, wildly inaccurate.  But the data is the data and it can be measured in a variety of ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(\lnot e|H)$ is the false negative probability - here, it is the probability that you test as not sick when you are actually sick. The test has incorrectly given the negative result.